# R - summarize and mutate by two columns incl. date

Tags: r, date, sorting, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to summarize a data set based on the time between, within a group. Basically what I have is, like this example, a data set where students buy a course, the courses have levels : 1 till 5, every course is about 2 months and students can just follow the courses from 1 till 5. I want to analyze when students:

- drop out. So that would be, when they have not bought a new course after 2 months
- What the last course was, after they have not bought a
  course in 2 months
- and if they, after they stopped later decided to
  continue again

my data set looks like this:

```
   InvoiceDate StudentName        Course                    
   <date>      <fct>             <fct>                                     
 1 2020-07-26  Tom                Level 1
 2 2019-11-05  Mike               Level 1    
 3 2019-11-05  Elsa               Level 1    
 4 2018-10-15  Mary               Level 1                                      
 5 2020-08-06  Mary               Level 2                                    
 6 2021-10-10  Mary               Level 3   
 7 2021-06-01  Stefan             Level 1       
 8 2021-06-01  Stefan             Party Ticket       
 9 2019-07-04  Julie              Level 1                          
10 2020-01-02  Julie              Level 2
```

I would like to end up with a data set like this:

```
   FullName  First_Buy         First_Course   Last_Course   Stopped_Date   Continued Course_Continued  Date_Continued      
 1 Tom       2020-07-26        Level 1        Level 1       2020-07-26      No        NA               NA             
 2 Mike      2019-11-05        Level 1        Level 1       2019-11-05      No        NA               NA             
 3 Elsa      2019-11-05        Level 1        Level 1       2019-11-05      No        NA               NA         
 4 Mary      2018-10-15        Level 1        Level 1       2018-10-15      Yes       Level 2          2020-08-06             
 5 Stefan    2021-06-01        Level 1        Level 1       2021-06-01      Yes       Party Ticket     2021-06-01
 6 Julie     2019-07-04        Level 1        Level 1       2019-07-04      Yes       Level 2          2020-01-02
```

I do have a start functions, but it gives me errors, which I don't understand..

What I have now is:

```
new_df <-df %>% 
  group_by(FullName) %>% 
  mutate(InvoiceDate = dmy(InvoiceDate),
         Diff_Months = abs((interval(InvoiceDate, lag(InvoiceDate, 
                                                      default = first(InvoiceDate))) %/% 
                              months(1)))) %>% 
  summarise(First_Buy = first(InvoiceDate),
            First_Course = first(InvoiceLineDescription),
            Last_Course = last(InvoiceLineDescription[Diff_Months <= 2]),
            Stopped_Date = InvoiceDate[InvoiceLineDescription == Last_Course],
            Continued = ifelse(Last_Course == last(InvoiceLineDescription), "No", "Yes"),
            Course_Continued = ifelse(Continued == "Yes", last(InvoiceLineDescription), NA))
```

But this gives me the following warning messages for each name:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` column `InvoiceDate`.
i `InvoiceDate = dmy(InvoiceDate)`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
i The warning occurred in group 1: FullName = Tom.
```

And it gives me the following new_df:

```
   FullName          First_Buy First_Course    Last_Course Stopped_Date Continued Course_Continued
   <fct>             <date>    <fct>           fct>       <date>       <lgl>     <lgl>           
 1 Tom               NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 2 Mike              NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 3 Elsa              NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 4 Mary              NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 5 Mary              NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 6 Mary              NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 7 Stefan            NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 8 Stefan            NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
 9 Julie             NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA              
10 Julie             NA        Level 1         NA          NA           NA        NA
```

It looks like it is not getting my date right, so I tried to change the format or type of that column, but so far nothing has worked. Somebody know how I can get to what I want :)?

Comment: The warning message suggests a problem with `InvoiceDate = dmy(InvoiceDate)`...looking at your data (is that `df`?), `InvoiceDate` is already a Date object? Or, you may want to double check the column in `df` to see how it is structured...is it really day-month-year character value that the `dmy` function is looking for?

Comment: Your dates are in the format year-month-day, so you want to use `ymd()`. `dmy()` would be for dates like `"28-02-2021"`.

Comment: Ah jeesh.... of course.... that worked, thank you so much for the quick response!